# With Range v3 ranges, how to combine views and actions into a single pipeline?

Tags: c++, stl, std, range-v3

I'm learning C++20 ranges (using [Range-V3-VS2015](https://github.com/microsoft/Range-V3-VS2015)). I have this code that works fine:

```
string clean;
auto tmp1 = input | view::remove_if(not_alpha) | view::transform(::tolower);
std::copy(tmp1.begin(), tmp1.end(), std::back_inserter(clean));
auto tmp2 = clean |= action::sort |  action::unique;
```

However, I would like to combine the two pipelines defining `tmp1` and `tmp2` into a single pipeline. Is that possible? I've tried numerous things, including adding `view::move` and `view::copy` in the middle, to no avail.

Comment: You aren’t supposed to take the address of standard library functions [anymore](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0551r3.pdf); use a lambda to call them.  (Yes, this is a bit silly for C library functions that C++ doesn’t overload.)

Comment: Why would you want to combine them into a single pipeline? Shouldn't it be the opposite - splitting these two pipelines into separate operations?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to use a conversion to materialise the view into an actual container to perform actions on it. I found a new piece of code in the range-v3 master branch introducing `range::v3::to<Container>` to perform such conversions.

`git blame` suggests that Eric started working on it this year (2019) and it is not really documented yet. However, I find `range-v3/test` pretty good learning material on how the library is used :)

I doubt that it is available in the VS2015 branch. However, Visual 2017 is already able to take the master branch of the library.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/action/sort.hpp>
#include <range/v3/action/unique.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace ranges::v3;
    std::string input = " 1a2a3Z4b5Z6cz ";
    std::string result = input
                       | view::filter(::isalpha)
                       | view::transform(::tolower)
                       | to<std::string>
                       | action::sort
                       | action::unique;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
abcz
```

which I believe is what you expect

Comment: Came here to say this. +1.

Comment: Thanks! As background and for my deeper understanding, why does this not work with either view::copy or view::move?

Answer (score 4):

[`ranges::to`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1206r1.pdf) is what you want.

Rolling your own semi-replacement is easy.

```
template<class C, class R>
C to_container( R&& r ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return C( begin(std::forward<R>(r)), end(std::forward<R>(r)) );
}
```

Not library-strength (lacks early failure as the biggest problem, and does not support `|`) but quite usable.

and then we just:

```
std::string r = to_container<std::string>( input | view::remove_if(not_alpha) | view::transform(::tolower) ) | action::sort |  action::unique;
```

Note that taking addresses of functions in `std` is [no longer advised](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0551r3.pdf) (via @DavisHerring in a comment above)

To upgrade to `|`:

```
template<class C>
struct to_container_t {
  template<class R>
  C operator()( R&& r )const {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    return C( begin(std::forward<R>(r)), end(std::forward<R>(r)) );
  }
  template<class R>
  friend C operator|( R&& r, to_container_t self ){
    return self( std::forward<R>(r) );
  }
};
template<class C>
constexpr to_container_t<C> to_container{};
```

Which gives us:

```
std::string r = input | view::remove_if(not_alpha) | view::transform(::tolower) | to_container<std::string> | action::sort |  action::unique;
```

As required.